# How to connect WebRTC to NodeJS server in SFU?

Tags: html, node.js, webrtc

I've been working on creating a voice chat system in the browser. I've asked a lot of questions here, and the consensus seems to be to use WebRTC in an SFU setup. I'm new to WebRTC. My question is, how do I use WebRTC on the browser, and connect it to a NodeJS server. I currently use ExpressJS for routing and Socket.IO for signalling, and I'm not against installing other packages. I've done a lot of Googling and can't hit any results. Anything helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can look out for [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/) for SFU architecture